# How to merge 2 pdf vector image assets in Swift

Tags: swift, image, pdf, uiimageview, vector-graphics

I have two vector images. I want to merge them so the dots appear on top of the first image.
The solutions for regular png assets don't work, as they use the actual size of the image, and the combined image comes out very blurry.

One solution that I found was placing a second UIImageView (same size, centred) on top of the first one, but it seems really dumb.

I need to make this inside the app because I also want to have the squared coloured differently (change the tint of the vector), and then merged with the black border image. So I can have 3 assets in my project (square, border and dots).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way to do this in an extension to UIImageView. Surprised that I couldn't find this anywhere.

```
extension UIImageView {

    func mergeTwoPDF(one: UIImage, two: UIImage) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        one.draw(in: areaSize, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
        two.draw(in: areaSize, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)
        //If you want to merge more than 2 images, just add them to the func parameters and repeat the line above with them
        let mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.image = mergedImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using sublayers:

```
["firstOne", "secondOne"].forEach {
let myLayer = CALayer()
let myImage = UIImage(named: $0)?.cgImage
myLayer.frame = myView.bounds
myLayer.contents = myImage
myView.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)
}
```

Or create a custom layer class